# How can I scan for new data in one database and send it to another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two databases on two servers.
The first one contains many tables which contains many codes.
An example is "Products" Table which contains the column "ProductCode".
Lets say there are 5 distinct records in that column i.e ProductCode1 -> ProductCode5.

The second database contains all the fields from each table defined in the first database.
I use the second database to provide definitions for each code found in the first database. I have migrated all the data from all the tables in the first db  over to the new one manually via an excel file and script.

However, I would like to create an SQL function which scans the first database and when it finds new rows of data, it adds that data to the second database.
This would save me the hassle of querying all the tables individually and then adding them manually, as i originally did.

Please note that both databases are stored on separate servers.
Is this possible to achieve?
Or is there any better options?

Answer (score 2):

While there are recovery backup and replication methods, if both databases maintain different data, there is no single, convenient *SQL function* to migrate new data in *all* tables from one database to another. However, you can build an .sql script or stored procedure that runs duplicate-avoid queries for new data.

Consider following steps where 1 and 2 are to be run for *each* table:

1. Create [Federated Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create-connection.html) from remote MySQL database to be locally available for querying but physical storage remains in remote database. See overview of [Federated Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-description.html). Note: this step needs to only be run once for each needed table.

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE federated_table ( 
      id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      other INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (id), INDEX name (name), 
      INDEX other_key (other) 
   ) 
   ENGINE=FEDERATED 
   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
   CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table
   ```

   Federated table schema must be identical to remote table. Therefore, align data types of `CREATE TABLE` to output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in remote database.

   [image: MySQL Federated Table Diagram]
2. Run SQL duplicate-avoid queries such as [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). One other method is `EXCEPT` (same family as `UNION` and `INTERSECT` operators):

   ```sql
   INSERT INTO Products (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
   SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
   FROM my_federated_products_table

   EXCEPT

   SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
   FROM Products
   ```
3. Automate step 2 for *each* table into a single [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) (or .sql script) to be run multiple times in future.

   ```sql
   DELIMITER $

   CREATE PROCEDURE migrate_new_data()
   BEGIN

      -- ALL INSERT INTO STATEMENTS FROM FEDERATED TABLES

   END $

   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Run procedure each time from Excel, workbench, command line, or elsewhere which can serve as your *SQL function*:

   ```sql
   CALL migrate_new_data;
   ```

Comment: I appreciate that answer but i think we are getting our wires crossed. I have two databases already created. I dont want to have to create a new table for this approach. I simply want to learn how to script it so that it gathers the new data from existing table and either prints it out for manually addition to the second database or it somehow adds it automatically to the other database. I do not wish to back up or replica. I simply want tio grab a code like "101" from db _1 and add it into db_2

Comment: You may not have read my answer closely. This is not a backup or replica solution. Federated tables are not *actual* tables that store data. Essentially, they are connection proxies that point to remote database tables. Coupled with `INSERT` queries, this solution does as you intend: *gathers the new data from existing table* and  *adds it automatically to the other database*. One point of clarification, you do not need to run `CREATE TABLE` each time only *once* in your destination database. And you cannot *grab a code like "101" from db _1 and add it into db_2* without referring to tables.

Comment: Is there not a way where i scan all the tables in database A for a column, and i can then compare it with the database B?

Comment: As mentioned, there is *no single, convenient SQL function* for your needs. But do note this answer shows if you do the hard work now, you can have such a simple one-line method as either a *single* stored procedure or *single* .SQL script of `INSERT` lines to use in the future. Also, the duplicate-avoid queries can be run infinite times and will not duplicate data, so will not pose a problem for accidental re-runs.

Comment: The stored procedure approach i have seen in some forums does not require federated tables being created. Also the solution mentiones that they have to have the same schema as the table in question, but all my tables have different schema.They are all set up differently.

Comment: Were the topics on those forums discussing migration across database servers in MySQL? Can't see how you can run append queries across servers without federated tables in MySQL. Also, same schema means matching the same, named table from source db to destination db where source holds the physically stored table and destination is federated table. Docs indicate they must match prior to connection. I add diagram to help visualize. But inserts can have different schema tables just align corresponding columns.

Comment: All in all, if you are newcomer to SQL or MySQL, this may be an advanced solution. Another alternative to this is use programming code (Java, Pyhon, PHP, etc.) to connect between both MySQL connections and run the table-to-table comparison.

Comment: Yeah im a novice tbh.  This is one approach i found but i dont understand it http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Comment: That is a solution for SQL Server (a different RDBMS than MySQL). And it uses [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) (close counterpart to Federated Tables) to query across servers.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I forgot to mention that i am using SQL server!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like FEDERATED Storage is what your are looking for.

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html):

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

Here is and article that shows how to configure it: https://medium.com/@techrandomthoughts/setting-up-federated-tables-in-mysql-8a17520b988c

Comment: i'm not looking to copy data. I would rather grab the column i want and insert it into the other database. In my scenario, the second db has a column called "CodeNo", this contains all possible codes from all the tables in database A